# Wordpress XML/RSS Reader Caused By Posts

Tags: xml, rss, wordpress

I am setting up a new wordpress installation and keep getting the below error on my RSS feed site.com/feed

```
error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

It occurs no matter which theme is activated. I have gone through the files and removed blank lines, but still get the error.

How can I troubleshoot this? Is there a plugin that might help? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this error arises if there is a whitespace before an XML declaration (`<?xml ... ?>`) appears in your feed. The blank line error means that the code has blank lines in it, which can be easily introduced in the WordPress php code by a plugin, theme, or any configuration file.

So basically you had to go looking for blank lines before PHP starting tag
`<?php`
and after the PHP closing tag
`?>`

Try disabling your plugins too. Here is a plugin you could give a try:
http://www.flyaga.info/fix-rss-feed-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: The fix rss feed plugin unfortunately does not work, disabled all other plugins.... so I need to go through every file in wordpress and delete every blank line? Does this error come from a particular file in wordpress? I have checked all the theme files, plugins are disabled.

Comment: As per your question, you are setting up a new wordpress installation. Try downloading latest wordpress zip and before adding any plugin or theme, just look in default structure. See if its working fine.