# Wordpress - inserts blank line in rss feed and source code- tried everything

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the same issue as this question:
[Wordpress XML/RSS Reader Caused By Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236954/wordpress-xml-rss-reader-caused-by-posts/20237205#20237205)

but as it's old, the solutions don't work.

**We recently upgraded php to 8.0 when the problem started.**

Here is my blog: https://libapps.libraries.uc.edu/liblog/
If I validate the feed:
{https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Flibapps.libraries.uc.edu%2Fliblog%2Ffeed}

Updraft plus recognizes the issue and gives me a warning:
"Warning: Your WordPress installation has a problem with outputting extra whitespace. This can corrupt backups that you download from here"

My current theme is default-2023

So far I have:

1. tried 3 different themes
2. Enabled debugging
3. Disabled ALL plugins
4. Reinstalled the latest wordpress version
5. Update all plugins
6. Updraft plus recognizes the issue and gives me a warning:
7. looked in the following:

   -rss2.php, functions.php, header.php, .htaccess, wp-settings.php, wp-load.php, wp-settings.php

I can not see any "extra lines" or spaces.

What can I further do?

- would something in the php setup cause this? php.ini?

---

-I do have a test instance on php 8 where this is NOT happening... is there a good way to transfer files from that to production?
-is there a php function I can add to the header.inc or some such to overcome this?
-any other ideas?